# Email not sent to mentions while creating issue in jira via email

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin

I have written some plugin for JIRA which create jira Issue using email. 
In this plugin I ask for a feedback and based on feedback , a jira issue is created.
Issue was created Successfully and All the mentions got tagged also. But plugin is not sending emails to tagged persons.
I searched, and I got information about MentionService (https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/mention/MentionService.html) API of jira.
But I am not able to use it as it is an interface and class which Implement this interface, MentionServiceImpl (https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/mention/MentionServiceImpl.html) is not available to import.
So can anyone please tell me, How I can use this class MentionServiceImpl in my code.

Thanks,

Comment: On issue creation, watchers are not notified, because the watcher list is filled _after_ the issue gets created. Edit: same for mentions.

Comment: Thanks Koshinae.
So can u suggest a way to do the same ?

Comment: Well, we have a "behaviour" based on the Behaviours plugin. It adds the users defined in the project metadata into a "Notification List" customfield, which itself has the type of Watcher Field (provided by a plugin with the same name, very handy). So it's only half of a workaround, as it adds predefined users into, not the real watchers...
It sucks real hard, but AFAIK there is no plan fixing this by vendor.